# Is there a list of my account sidebar link names for use with removeLinkByName module?

Tags: magento-1, theme, layout

When trying to remove my account links in the sidebar, using the module outlined here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/435/#e9

Is there a list of all the names that are associated with each link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full list of names for those links are:

```
    recurring_profiles      <!-- Recurring Profiles -->
    billing_agreements      <!-- Billing Agreements -->
    tags                    <!-- My Tags -->
    OAuth Customer Tokens   <!-- My Applications -->
    downloadable_products   <!-- Downloadable Products -->
    reviews                 <!-- Product Reviews -->
    wishlist                <!-- Wishlist -->
    address_book            <!-- Address book -->
    account_edit            <!-- Account information -->
    account                 <!-- Account dashboard -->
    newsletter              <!-- Newsletter -->
    orders                  <!-- Orders-->
```

You can add these after creating that module by adding the following for each link to your local.xml:

```
<action method="removeLinkByName"><name>recurring_profiles</name></action>      <!-- Recurring Profiles -->
```